Asp.NET Core: OpenAPI buildtime generated specs file does not include prefix
I am trying to generate a specifications file at buildtime for my controllers using OpenApi.
I included this in the csproj file:
<OpenApiDocumentsDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/ApiSpecs</OpenApiDocumentsDirectory>
<OpenApiGenerateDocumentsOnBuild>true</OpenApiGenerateDocumentsOnBuild>

It generates a file but the routes in the file do not include the prefix I've set in Program.cs: RouteGroupBuilder apiGroup = app.MapGroup("/my/prefix"); The prefix is not visible in swagger either but I managed to add it using options.PreSerializeFilter. The problem is that I need the specs generated at buildtime and the solution for swagger works only at runtime.







@CharlesHenington please don't answer in comments

@gilliduck my apologies, I had to leave for work, and it wasn't allowing me to post it as an answer for some reason. It said needed at least 30 characters but stated that I had typed 0 characters.
